# Images not uploading for User avatar (Active storage)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image-uploading, rails-activestorage

I'm trying to upload avatars for existing users in my rails app using ActiveStorage, but after uploading an image through the devise edit page, it doesn't display the image.

User model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one_attached :avatar
end
```

Application_controller

```
def configure_permitted_parameters
 devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update) { |u| u.permit(:username, :first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :currentpassword, :remember_me, :avatar)}
end
```

devise/registrations/edit.html.erb

```
<div class="field">
  <% if @user.avatar.attached? %>
    <%= image_tag @user.avatar %>
  <% end %>
</div>

<div class="field">
  Upload a Profile Picture
  <%= f.label "Profile Picture"  %>
  <%= f.file_field :avatar %>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried my [answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57507159/2190621)

Answer (score 0):

You should permit parameters like this:

```
devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: [:username, :first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :currentpassword, :remember_me, :avatar])
```

Comment: i've tried this but the avatar image still doesn't upload

Comment: Hi guys! I have the same issue, ¿You have any suggestions?